# i have a problem with my shortest path function that should use algorithm to solve this problem

Tags: python, nodes

The main function in this program first loads data into memory (the directory from which the data is loaded can be specified by a command-line argument). Then, the function prompts the user to type in two names. The person_id_for_name function retrieves the id for any person (and handles prompting the user to clarify, in the event that multiple people have the same name). The function then calls the shortest_path function to compute the shortest path between the two people, and prints out the path.
Anyway when i give the two names that i know for a fact that are connected it says "Not connected".

THIS IS THE MAIN:

```
import csv
import sys

from util import Node, StackFrontier, QueueFrontier

# Maps names to a set of corresponding person_ids
names = {}

# Maps person_ids to a dictionary of: name, birth, movies (a set of movie_ids)
people = {}

# Maps movie_ids to a dictionary of: title, year, stars (a set of person_ids)
movies = {}


def load_data(directory):
    """
    Load data from CSV files into memory.
    """
    # Load people
    with open(f"{directory}/people.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            people[row["id"]] = {
               "name": row["name"],
                "birth": row["birth"],
                "movies": set()
            }
            if row["name"].lower() not in names:
                names[row["name"].lower()] = {row["id"]}
            else:
               names[row["name"].lower()].add(row["id"])

    # Load movies
    with open(f"{directory}/movies.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            movies[row["id"]] = {
                "title": row["title"],
                "year": row["year"],
                "stars": set()
            }

                
    
    
    # Load stars
    with open(f"{directory}/stars.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                people[row["person_id"]]["movies"].add(row["movie_id"])
                movies[row["movie_id"]]["stars"].add(row["person_id"])
            except KeyError:
                pass


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python degrees.py [directory]")
    directory = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else "large"

    # Load data from files into memory
    print("Loading data...")
    load_data(directory)
    print("Data loaded.")

    source = person_id_for_name(input("Name: "))
    if source is None:
        sys.exit("Person not found.")
    target = person_id_for_name(input("Name: "))
    if target is None:
        sys.exit("Person not found.")

    path = shortest_path(source, target)


    if path is None:
        print("Not connected.")
    else:
        degrees = len(path)
        print(f"{degrees} degrees of separation.")
        path = [(None, source)] + path
        for i in range(degrees):
            person1 = people[path[i][1]]["name"]
            person2 = people[path[i + 1][1]]["name"]
            movie = movies[path[i + 1][0]]["title"]
            print(f"{i + 1}: {person1} and {person2} starred in {movie}")




def shortest_path(source, target):
    """
    Returns the shortest list of (movie_id, person_id) pairs
    that connect the source to the target.

    If no possible path, returns None.
    """
    # Keep track of number of states explored
    num_explored = 0

    # Initialize frontier to just the starting position
    start = Node(state=source, parent=None, action=None)
    frontier = StackFrontier()
    frontier.add(start)

    # Initialize an empty explored set
    explored = set()

    # Keep looping until solution found
    while True:

        # If nothing left in frontier, then no path
        if frontier.empty():
            raise Exception("no solution")

        # Choose a node from the frontier
        node = frontier.remove()
        num_explored += 1


        #Mark node as explored
        explored.add(node.state)


        # Add neighbors to frontier
        for movie_id, person_id in neighbors_for_person(node.state):
            if not frontier.contains_state(person_id) and person_id not in explored:
                child = Node(state=person_id, parent=node, action=movie_id)
                frontier.add(child)

                # If node is the goal, then we have a solution
                if child.state == target:
                    movies = []
                    people = []
                    solution = []
                    while node.parent is not None:
                        movies.append(child.action)
                        people.append(child.state)
                        child = child.parent
                    movies.reverse()
                    people.reverse()
                    x = zip(movies, people)
                    for movie, person in x:
                        solution.append((movie, person))
                    return
                frontier.add(child)



def person_id_for_name(name):
    """
    Returns the IMDB id for a person's name,
    resolving ambiguities as needed.
    """
    person_ids = list(names.get(name.lower(), set()))
    if len(person_ids) == 0:
        return None
    elif len(person_ids) > 1:
        print(f"Which '{name}'?")
        for person_id in person_ids:
            person = people[person_id]
            name = person["name"]
            birth = person["birth"]
            print(f"ID: {person_id}, Name: {name}, Birth: {birth}")
        try:
            person_id = input("Intended Person ID: ")
            if person_id in person_ids:
                return person_id
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return None
    else:
        return person_ids[0]


def neighbors_for_person(person_id):
    """
    Returns (movie_id, person_id) pairs for people
    who starred with a given person.
    """
    movie_ids = people[person_id]["movies"]
    neighbors = set()
    for movie_id in movie_ids:
        for person_id in movies[movie_id]["stars"]:
            neighbors.add((movie_id, person_id))
    return neighbors


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

THIS IS THE UTILS.PY FILE:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, state, parent, action):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action


class StackFrontier():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frontier = []

    def add(self, node):
        self.frontier.append(node)

    def contains_state(self, state):
        return any(node.state == state for node in self.frontier)

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.frontier) == 0

    def remove(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise Exception("empty frontier")
        else:
            node = self.frontier[-1]
            self.frontier = self.frontier[:-1]
            return node


class QueueFrontier(StackFrontier):

    def remove(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise Exception("empty frontier")
        else:
            node = self.frontier[0]
            self.frontier = self.frontier[1:]
            return node
```

It shoul output 1 degree of separation between Kevin Bacon and Tom Cruise that are listed in a csv file but it doesn't, it says that they are not connected, which i know isn't true